# Is there plot_predictions function in utils module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I am getting an error when I run the following command:

```
from utils import plot_predictions
```

> ImportError Traceback (most recent call last) in 
>   ----> 1 from utils import plot_predictions
>
> ImportError: cannot import name 'plot_predictions'

Comment: What `utils` module are you talking about? Could you give its link? I think it's `utils.py` file you're importing, which may be somewhere in your workspace.

Comment: I was running the code using Jupyter Notebook which I got from GitHub. Below is the link. https://github.com/borisbanushev/stockpredictionai

Comment: He must have defined a function `plot_predictions` in `utils.py` file. But the file is not available on GitHub. That's why the error.

Comment: Yes, that's very much possible. Many Thanks